# where is model.ser.gz located in stanford corenlp?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford corenlp.when I execute the file SentimentTraining.java it requires model.ser.gz but I am unable to find that in the downloaded package of corenlp.Can you tell how do i find model.ser.gz

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `model.ser.gz` might be referring to, but if you're not specifying a custom model it's likely this resource is in the models JAR.

Make sure you are running your project with the CoreNLP models archive (distributed with CoreNLP, named in the most recent version `stanford-corenlp-3.3.1-models.jar`) on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

`model.ser.gz` is not included in the package. Rather it is what you create when you run the SentimentTraining code while passing it a PTB-style trainer. Once you create the model you can pass it as an argument to get new sentiment values on your test set. The Deeply Moving Deep Mining website has more information on this if you are interested.